# Is it possible to exit a country with one passport and enter that country again with another passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, covid-19, egypt

A friend of mine has exited Egypt with the American passport. But due to the current situation, she won't be able to return back to Egypt with the American passport; only those who have Egyptian passports could return back.

If she manages to issue an Egyptian passport, would it be possible to enter Egypt with it?
She is Egyptian and has an Egyptian national ID but not passport.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's safest to use the same passport for any given country until that passport expires.  If it's necessary to switch for any given country, it's best to switch while you're outside that country unless you reside in the country.

Someone with multiple nationalities must choose which nationality to use.  The choice of nationality may or may not be free: some countries require their citizens to present themselves as such to border authorities.  Similarly, someone with a right of permanent or temporary residence in a country may be constrained to a particular nationality when dealing with that country's border authorities.

In this case, the person is a dual national of the country in question, but used her foreign passport to leave that country.  There is another general rule that applies to this case, which is that countries must generally admit their own citizens.  Therefore, someone in this position should generally be allowed to enter her country of nationality with that country's passport, regardless of the documents she used leaving the country.

However, I do not know Egypt's stance on dual nationality.  Perhaps she violated some law by leaving with her US passport, and perhaps returning with an Egyptian passport would expose her to a fine or other punishment, or to loss of Egyptian nationality.  There may be other specific considerations that make it inadvisable to use her Egyptian passport.

Comment: FWIW, the reasons why Egyptian citizenship may be lost or withdrawn and Egypt’s stance on dual nationality are listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_nationality_law

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Passengers are not allowed to enter Egypt until 31 March 2020.

So wait until after tomorrow and I'll have a look at what happens then